# Google sheets formula to calculate hours elapsed between two datetime stamps & exclude weekends

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

What is the best formula to calculate the hh:mm:ss lapsed between end datetime and start datetime and also exclude weekends?  I know I can simply subtract end and start datetime ( End Datetime - Start DateTime) but I don't know how to exclude weekends from the formulas.

| Start DateTime | End DateTime | Response Time in hh:mm:ss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29 Oct 2021 6:56:14 | 30 Oct 2021 8:13:11 |  |
| 22 Oct 2021 16:26:04 | 25 Oct 2021 20:08:24 |  |
| 14 Oct 2021 2:36:34 | 20 Oct 2021 18:20:58 |  |
| 20 Oct 2021 6:56:14 | 20 Oct 2021 8:13:11 |  |

Answer (score 1):

Use `DAYS` to calculate the total number of days between two days, and `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` to calculate the number of days excluding weekends. The difference is the number of days (net of weekends). Deduct this from the number of days from the simple formula `End Datetime - Start DateTime)`

Use this formula:

`=(B3-A3)-((if(days(B3,A3)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A3,B3,1)<0,0,days(B3,A3)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A3,B3,1)))*1)`

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]

---

**Logic**

- `(B3-A3)` - calculate raw duration
- `days(B3,A3)` - calculate number of days difference
- `NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A3,B3,1)` - calculate days difference excluding weekends
- `if(days(B3,A3)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A3,B3,1)<0,0,days(B3,A3)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A3,B3,1))` - calculate the difference
- `if... * 1` - calculate duration
- `(B3-A3) - if... * 1` - deduct weekends from raw duration